# PHP: Echoing a JQuery Alert from case statement

Tags: javascript, php, html, echo, alert

I am trying to `echo` a JQuery `alert` from PHP. The method I am using is to echo the entire script tags  and then the JQuery within it. JQuery is working because alerts elsewhere work. the JQuery library is loaded before the code i am trying so it is not that.

below is my current statement:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); #server timezone
    $now = date('His'); #current time
    $cl = '173000'; #closing time
    $op = '084500'; #opening time

    switch (true) {
        case $now < $cl && $now > $op:
            echo "open
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    alert('open');
                });
            </script>
            ";
            break;

        case $now > $cl && $now < $op:
            echo 'closed';
            break;

        default:
            echo("neither closed nor open.  dun dun duuuuun");
            break;
    }
```

I know the statement is working to some extent because the open string is displayed. I also see the script tags yet they don't seem to execute see below:

---

**This image shows that the open text just before the script is echo'd into the page**

[image: The script is wrote into the page but not terminated]

---

**This image shows that the script tag is put into the page but is not executed**

[image: This is where the open text works]

---

## Update:

The answer was that JQuery hadn't actually loaded like i thought it had. the version number was wrong. for some reason it was:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have now changed it to:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

the reason I left the 2.x.x out is because the hosted library will choose the most up to date version of 2 now.

Comment: Are you echo'ing the javascript to the <head> or <body>? May be worth printing it to the bottom of the page, before the closing </body> if your not already.

Comment: Why don't you just set a variable and let your view/temlate/html handle the alert? Do you get any console errors? Do you load jQuery prior to the injected script tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have jQuery loaded at that moment you want to alert?
By the way, If you want to just `alert` something, you don't really need jQuery, just use:

`<script>alert('open');</script>`

Comment: I am using JQuery because it will  be a lengthy statement. Itsa was jsut to test it had loaded the alert

Comment: Sure, so I guess, as all the other comments and answer here, that jQuery is either not loaded at all or loaded too late (i.e. after the script is executed).

Comment: it was a noob error but you was right, i will accept answer in 3 minutes, thanks. picnic. problem in seat not in computer

Answer (score 1):

This can be a few issues.

is the jQuery library actually included on the page? also check the console logs for any errors. any javascript error on the page will prevent any other javascript from executing.